# CUDA texture origin location i

Tags: cuda

Is location in a texture at 0,0 in the centre of the texture or in the upper left hand corner?
e.g 
[
0,0 0,1 0,2
1,0 ... 1,2
2,0 2,1 2,2
]
or 
[
1,-1 0,1 1,1
0,-1 0,0 0,1
-1,-1 0,-1 1,-1
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[0,0] is not in the center of a texture.

Refer to the [texture fetching reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-fetching) in the programming guide.

Textures have a "non-normalized" address which spans from [0..N-1] per dimension.
Textures have a corresponding "normalized" address which spans from [0.0 .. 1.0]

You may also be interested in reading about the [texture addressing mode](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#texture-and-surface-memory) parameter, which defines how "out-of-range" texture addresses are handled.